# NPC: Reduction of VC to 2VC

Tags: np-complete

A professor gave us this problem, which I could not solve:
**Reduce VC to 2VC.** (Prove that 2VC is NPC)

**Definition:** 2VC gets G, and K, and returns true if there are 2 different VC in size K in G. (In the same way that double clique finds 2 clicks in size K)

**Note:** The problem was not written in English, so my translation might be slightly mistaken.

How should I go about solving it?

So far, I tried duplicating the graph, in the same way double-clique is reduced, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I suppose "NPC" means NP-complete, but what is VC and 2VC?

Comment: VC - known problem called Vertex Cover. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover, 2VC is defined above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two new vertices joined by an edge, and adjust $k$ appropriately.

Comment: why did you edit out "k+1"? what case doesn't hold with k+1?

Comment: @Amit: I decided to give a slightly less complete solution, is all.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is so simple and elegant.